# Height of a cone given its radius

Tags: integration, analytic-geometry

this is my first time posting. I have tried this solving this question but am unable to find a solution. We are supposed to use integration. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

> Question: An ice cream cone has radius 2.5 cm at the top. If a scoop of ice cream in the form of a sphere with radius 4 cm is placed on top of the cone, what percentage of the ice cream is outside the cone?

Height of the cone is not provided in the original question, so I am stuck on how to solve this.

Volume of ice cream $= \frac43π4^3 = 256π/3$

Volume of cone $= π6.25\frac h3$

Percentage of ice cream outside of cone = [(Volume of ice cream - Volume of cone)/Volume of ice cream]*100

Comment: The height of the cone isn't particularly relevant.  You only need to consider the circle that is the edge of the cone and where it meets the sphere.  This boundary will divide a spherical cap on one side of the circle from the bulk of the sphere.

Comment: Draw an isosceles triangle with a circle set partway below the "base" and the center of the circle above the base.  If you draw in a radius of the circle to one end of the triangle's base, the "Pythagorean" Theorem tells you how far above the base ("mouth" of the ice-cream cone) the center of the sphere (ice-cream scoop) is located.  That gives you an essential measurement for your volume integration.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I am not smart, but do you mean use Pythagorean Theorem like so: (2.5)^2 + 4^2 = c^2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your ice cream cone.

[image]

Your volume is:

$\int_{-h}^4 (4^2 - x^2) \ dx$

You will need to use the Pythagorean theorem to find $h.$

And I would suggest you think on what $4^2 - x^2$ might actually represent.